# No CSS errors are reported but border-image-source and border-image-slice don't produce any border image

Tags: css

I am practicing and trying to display an image for a border. I created the image and it can be [found here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sathyaish/Practice/master/CSS/images/Border.png).

[image]

I am running Firefox 60.0.1 64-bit.

I checked the **Network** tab in Developer Tools and the image loads just fine. Also my `@supports` *at-rule* works just fine. And there are no CSS errors.

However, I don't see the border image at all.

```css
div {
        width: 250px;
        height: 120px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(40, 180, 255, 0.9), rgba(40, 100, 255, 0.9));

        font-size: 2em;
        font-family: Geneva;

        margin: 100px auto 0px auto;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    @supports (border-image-source: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sathyaish/Practice/master/CSS/images/Border.png)) {
        div {
            border-image-source: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sathyaish/Practice/master/CSS/images/Border.png);
            border-image-slice: 30%;
            border-image-repeat: round;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div>This is a nice div.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `border` property with some width:

```css
div {
  border: 20px solid orange;
  width: 250px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(40, 180, 255, 0.9), rgba(40, 100, 255, 0.9));
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Geneva;
  margin: 100px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

@supports (border-image-source: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sathyaish/Practice/master/CSS/images/Border.png)) {
  div {
    border-image-source: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sathyaish/Practice/master/CSS/images/Border.png);
    border-image-slice: 30%;
    border-image-repeat: round;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>This is a nice div.</div>
```